# Android, access all notifications

Tags: android, notifications

In Android, if a user sets "Show Notifications" of a specific App to off, is the notification still created? If yes, is it somehow possible to access these created but not shown notifications?

Answer (score 0):

As an example, consider that to create a Status bar Notification, below code is used:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

And to POST this notification, below code is used:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

But since the "Show Notification" is OFF, above code don't show the Notification on Status bar.
 So as you can see, although the `NotificationCompat.Builder` has CREATED a Notification object/instance and filled it with other details such as Title or Text etc. you can NOT access it as it is NOT Allowed to POST by System because of user's preference settings.

Also, Since Android 4.1, users can turn off notifications of an app from application manager, but there is NO API to acheive the same from Application code (on Non-rooted device,that is). And It is not possible to disable notifications from other apps, and you can only control notifications generated by your own app.

Few more pointers that you must have in mind:
1.As a developer we have no way to know whether a call to notify was effective or not. So if I really need to check if the notifications are disabled for the current application there is NO Such setting for that in the API.
2.You really shouldn't concern yourself with it. Just assume your notification was successful. If the user has explicitly disabled your notifications, then he/she probably had good reason to do so, and your application should not care whether the notification was displayed or not